# is there a way to produce SVG with ipyvega?

Tags: jupyter, vega

Currently the jupyter output seems to only give a canvas element. Vega does allow SVG output but I couldn't see a way to do it from ipyvega.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Click on the "Open In Vega Editor" link under the rendered plot, use the drop-down menu in the upper-right to change the renderer to "SVG", and then click the "Export" button.

I'm also working on a way to programmatically export PNG & SVG from Python within the related Altair project; you can see the relevant code [here](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/blob/master/altair/utils/node.py). We could move this functionality to ipyvega in the future if people would find it useful.

Comment: thanks Jake, this works great if the data is already in the vega spec but not if the data is in a topojson file. So far, my best solution is to simply make a html page with the appropriate vega content and go from there.

Comment: You could also install the vega package on nodejs and use the vg2svg command to do the conversion locally.